# Functional-style Programming in Red (Arguments passed by val vs by ref)

Tags: function, parameters, series

I've purchased and making my way through the Red Programming book recently available from Pakt.

On p. 112 in the chapter relating to functions, something caught my eye:

- Scalar values are passed by value, which means that a copy of the value is sent to the function
- Other values are passed by reference, which means that a reference to the value is sent to the function

When I first got into ML and the Functional paradigm, what I loved was the fact that nothing was passed around by reference.  This gave me the confidence that whatever I was doing inside a function would not affect anything outside of it.

But here in Red, series (which I could compare to a ML list), are passed to a function by reference, which means whatever I do to it inside a function will most certainly alter the list at the source.

Are there any options to pass a series by value, as it does with scalars, or is the only way to achieve this to make a copy of the parameter, and have the function work on this copy?

Regards,

yves